# Joining on a single row ID table vs a constant results in extremly slow query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'id_name_str' AS Id) t1
LEFT JOIN ( ... ) t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

This takes 3ms to run.

However, if I do the following it takes an extremely long time (I quit the query after 15min)

```
create table #idtable
(
 Id varchar(16) not null PRIMARY KEY
) 

insert into #idtable(Id)
select Id
from (SELECT 'id_name_str' as Id)

SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id FROM #idtable) t1
LEFT JOIN ( ... ) t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

The left join is doing lots of stuff processing on 100,000 Ids and 10's of millions of rows.

But what is happening in the scenarios I gave above?

Comment: Look at the execution plans for both... Best way to find out "what is happening in the scenarios you gave"

Comment: why not SELECT Id directly and join, why do 2 SELECT statements since the second SELECT just *reflects* the first?

Comment: Take a look at the queries execution plan. It should reveal what is happening under the hood.

Comment: @NikosM Its just for clarity and alignment with the previous query. Either way doesn't make a difference. As for showing the execution plan, its rather large, but I was hoping something would be familiar with this problem without an execution plan. Otherwise, I will provide one.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this on SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
create table #idtable
(
 Id varchar(16) not null PRIMARY KEY
) 

insert into #idtable(Id)
select Id
from (SELECT 'id_name_str' as Id) x1
create table dbo.t2 (t2 varchar(16), id1 int identity)

create table dbo.t2 (id varchar(16), id1 int identity)
insert into dbo.t2 values ('abc'),('def'), ('id_name_str')
go 5000
;

SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id FROM #idtable) t1
LEFT JOIN ( select * from t2) t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

the insert/go 5000 took a little while (should have used a cross join) but the select was close to 0 time. Notice I had to add a table alias to the left join.

Notice I did not create a key (in real life would have clustered t2) and yet it was very fast. Your description of the problem is missing something crucial.

I also think that SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id FROM #idtable) t1
LEFT JOIN ( select * from t2) t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id

is the same as:

select t1.id,t2.* from #idtable t1 left join t2.

on t1.id = t2.id

Whats with all the subqueries?

Comment: Of course a query against just 5k rows is "very fast". But the question is not about speed, but about unnecessary work done. You'd have to examine the query plan to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do sth like this (per my comment above as well):

```
SELECT * FROM t2
WHERE t2.Id IN (SELECT Id From t1)
```

This removes the JOIN clause which is slow in general, in any case the 2 combined SELECT statements are redundant in some way since the one just *reflects* the other (and then joined), so simplify it

[SQL SERVER IN clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server obviously thinks there may be may more rows in your temporary table then there really are.  Does it help if you run:

```
update statistics #idtable;
```

before executing the main query?

As a side note, you're using more subqueries than I would.  Consider shortening this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id FROM #idtable) t1
```

to just:

```
SELECT * FROM #idtable t1
```

And instead of the following (which looks like a syntax error to me because there is no alias for the subquery after `from`):

```
insert into #idtable(Id)
select Id
from (SELECT 'id_name_str' as Id)
```

You can write:

```
insert into #idtable(Id)
select 'id_name_str'
```

Or you can omit the column list (it defaults to all columns), omit the optional `into`, and use the `values` clause instead of `select`:

```
insert #idtable
values ('id_name_str')
```